# printing row-based data in a table format on python

Tags: python

I have the below data in an array each line represents each index

```
col1 col2 col3 subcol1 subcol2 subcol3
[3 spaces]subcol4 subcol5 subcol6
[2 spaces]col4 subcol7 subcol8 subcol9
[3 spaces]subcol10 subcol11 subcol2
```

I want to convert this data as shown below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
col1  | col2 | col3  |   subcol1  | subcol2 | subcol13     
                       --------------------------------
      |      |       |   subcol4  | subcol5 | subcol6
              -----------------------------------------         
      |      | col4  |   subcol7  | subcol8 | subcol9     
                       --------------------------------
      |      |       |   subcol10 | subcol11| subcol12  
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can accomplish that with a script, show us yours, we'll show you ours.

Comment: @Julien script in the sense shell script or python script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tabulate for pretty similar results: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate

Setup:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

data = [
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'subcol1', 'subcol2', 'subcol3'],
    ['', '', '', 'subcol4', 'subcol5', 'subcol6'],
    ['', '', 'col4', 'subcol7', 'subcol8', 'subcol9'],
    ['', '', '', 'subcol10', 'subcol11', 'subcol2'],
]
```

Then print:

```
print tabulate(data[1:], headers=data[0], tablefmt='orgtbl')
```

Which will resolve to:

```
| col1   | col2   | col3   | subcol1   | subcol2   | subcol3   |
|--------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|        |        |        | subcol4   | subcol5   | subcol6   |
|        |        | col4   | subcol7   | subcol8   | subcol9   |
|        |        |        | subcol10  | subcol11  | subcol2   |
```

Or without headers:

```
print tabulate(data, tablefmt='orgtbl')
```

Which will resolve to:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | subcol1  | subcol2  | subcol3 |
|      |      |      | subcol4  | subcol5  | subcol6 |
|      |      | col4 | subcol7  | subcol8  | subcol9 |
|      |      |      | subcol10 | subcol11 | subcol2 |
```

Other available options for 'tablefmt' parameter

```
- "plain"
- "simple"
- "grid"
- "fancy_grid"
- "pipe"
- "orgtbl"
- "jira"
- "psql"
- "rst"
- "mediawiki"
- "moinmoin"
- "html"
- "latex"
- "latex_booktabs"
- "textile"
```